# How to set spring active profile when testing Struts2

Tags: spring, junit, struts2, struts2-junit-plugin

When testing an stand alone spring environment we can do:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:spring-*.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles(  profiles = { "Prod","bsi"})
public class SampleTest
```

When testing Struts 2 with spring integration we can use:

```
public class SessionManagement extends StrutsSpringTestCase  {

    @Override
    public String[] getContextLocations() {

      return new String[] {"classpath:spring-*.xml"};

    }
}
```

But how can I set the active spring profile here?

Comment: @RomanC can you please explain what I should done ?!

Comment: So annotations didn't work for you?

Comment: No the annotations did not worked

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi it's interesting what did you try to do, what is not working, what errors you have, why do you think it should work, and so on. Write a simple testcase with profiles.

Comment: It seems that some the spring can not inject some beans.

Comment: Spring can't inject beans either they are not beans or has not configuration for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set active profiles in spring via application context environment.

Since `StrutsTestCase` uses `GenericXmlContextLoader` which is not configurable you need to override `setupBeforeInitDispatcher` method in your test and use some context (e.g. `XmlWebApplicationContext`) where you can set profiles and call `refresh`.

```
@Override
protected void setupBeforeInitDispatcher() throws Exception {
    // only load beans from spring once
    if (applicationContext == null) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        webApplicationContext.setConfigLocations(getContextLocations());
        webApplicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("Prod", "bsi");
        webApplicationContext.refresh();

        applicationContext = webApplicationContext;
    }

    servletContext.setAttribute(
            WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE,
            applicationContext);
}
```

#### JUnit 4

Since you're using JUnit 4 there is `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase` abstract class. Extend it and you can use annotations just like in your `SampleTest`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:spring-*.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "Prod","bsi"})
public class SessionManagement extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase<SomeAction>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply. I can not find where to put your code. I tried the `setUp` method but no luck.  I try to do set environment variable `spring.profiles.active=Prod,bsi` but it did not worked.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi It turned out a little trickier. See an update.

Comment: I tested the JUNIT 4 approach and it worked! Thanks.